# Hibernate and using a database index creates an SQL syntax error on CockroachDB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, kotlin, cockroachdb

The following minimal example using a database index with Spring Boot, Hibernate, JpaRepository, CockroachDB and Kotlin fails to restart.

I also tested with PostgresSQL instead of CockroachDB and this is fine.

```
|------------------------------------------|
|           |  PostgresSQL  |  CockroachDB |
|-----------+---------------+--------------|
| no index  |  OK           |  OK          |
| index     |  OK           |  ERROR       |
|------------------------------------------|
```

With CockroachDB however it ends in an SQL syntax error (see logs at the end of this question).

This is the code to reproduce the issue.

---

`./src/main/kotlin/ThingService.kt`:

```
package things

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Index
import javax.persistence.Column

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

interface ThingRepository : JpaRepository<Thing, Long> {
}

@RestController
class ThingController(private val repository: ThingRepository) {
}

@Entity
@Table(indexes = [Index(name="value", columnList="value")])
data class Thing (
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    var id: Long,
    @Column(name="value")
    var value: String
)

@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

---

`./src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
server.port=8082

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/things_db?sslmode=disable
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

---

`./build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.2.20"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.0.0.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core")
    compile("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("org.json:json:20180130")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(module = "junit")
    }
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
}
```

---

What follows are the steps to reproduce the problem.

Download and initialize CockroachDB:

```
# download
wget -qO- https://binaries.cockroachdb.com/cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64.tgz | tar xvz

# start
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach start --insecure
# leave terminal open in background

# init
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "CREATE USER root WITH PASSWORD '123';"
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "CREATE DATABASE things_db;"
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "GRANT ALL ON DATABASE things_db TO root;"
```

Run data service:

```
gradle bootRun
# wait until started
# then ctrl+c to stop
```

Now let's have a look at the generated table int the database:

```
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "SHOW COLUMNS FROM things_db.thing;"
```

output:

```
# Server version: CockroachDB CCL v1.1.6 (linux amd64, built 2018/03/12 17:58:05, go1.8.3) (same version as client)
# Cluster ID: 2f85d639-a096-4ebc-a478-216a4e7e3a14
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
| Field |    Type     | Null  | Default |          Indices          |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
| id    | BIGINT      | false | NULL    | {"primary","value_index"} |
| value | STRING(255) | true  | NULL    | {"value_index"}           |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
(2 rows)
```

then

```
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "SHOW INDEXES FROM things_db.thing;"
```

output

```
# Server version: CockroachDB CCL v1.1.6 (linux amd64, built 2018/03/12 17:58:05, go1.8.3) (same version as client)
# Cluster ID: 2f85d639-a096-4ebc-a478-216a4e7e3a14
+-------+-------------+--------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+----------+
| Table |    Name     | Unique | Seq | Column | Direction | Storing | Implicit |
+-------+-------------+--------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+----------+
| thing | primary     | true   |   1 | id     | ASC       | false   | false    |
| thing | value_index | false  |   1 | value  | ASC       | false   | false    |
| thing | value_index | false  |   2 | id     | ASC       | false   | true     |
+-------+-------------+--------+-----+--------+-----------+---------+----------+
(3 rows)
```

---

However running

```
gradle bootRun
```

a second time does not work. The application crashes on start-up.

This is an excerpt of [the log of the second (failing) run](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/a9f0dbd71d20d6aa6fcfbf08070515ca):

```
2018-03-18 10:57:06.419 ERROR 28412 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Detail: source SQL:
SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM,   ct.relname AS TABLE_NAME, NOT i.indisunique AS NON_UNIQUE,   NULL AS INDEX_QUALIFIER, ci.relname AS INDEX_NAME,   CASE i.indisclustered     WHEN true THEN 1    ELSE CASE am.amname       WHEN 'hash' THEN 2      ELSE 3    END   END AS TYPE,   (i.keys).n AS ORDINAL_POSITION,   trim(both '"' from pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(ci.oid, (i.keys).n, false)) AS COLUMN_NAME,   CASE am.amcanorder     WHEN true THEN CASE i.indoption[(i.keys).n - 1] & 1       WHEN 1 THEN 'D'       ELSE 'A'     END     ELSE NULL   END AS ASC_OR_DESC,   ci.reltuples AS CARDINALITY,   ci.relpages AS PAGES,   pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(i.indpred, i.indrelid) AS FILTER_CONDITION FROM pg_catalog.pg_class ct   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (ct.relnamespace = n.oid)   JOIN (SELECT i.indexrelid, i.indrelid, i.indoption,           i.indisunique, i.indisclustered, i.indpred,           i.indexprs,           information_schema._pg_expandarray(i.indkey) AS keys         FROM pg_catalog.pg_index i) i     ON (ct.oid = i.indrelid)   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ci ON (ci.oid = i.indexrelid)   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_am am ON (ci.relam = am.oid) WHERE true  AND n.nspname = 'things_db' AND ct.relname = 'thing' ORDER BY NON_UNIQUE, TYPE, INDEX_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
2018-03-18 10:57:06.420  WARN 28412 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-03-18 10:57:06.420  INFO 28412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-03-18 10:57:06.421  INFO 28412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-03-18 10:57:06.422  INFO 28412 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-03-18 10:57:06.432  INFO 28412 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-18 10:57:06.433 ERROR 28412 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        // truncated to fit post
        at things.ThingServiceKt.main(ThingService.kt:40) [main/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing index information: things_db.thing
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        // truncated to fit post
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Detail: source SQL:
SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM,   ct.relname AS TABLE_NAME, NOT i.indisunique AS NON_UNIQUE,   NULL AS INDEX_QUALIFIER, ci.relname AS INDEX_NAME,   CASE i.indisclustered     WHEN true THEN 1    ELSE CASE am.amname       WHEN 'hash' THEN 2      ELSE 3    END   END AS TYPE,   (i.keys).n AS ORDINAL_POSITION,   trim(both '"' from pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(ci.oid, (i.keys).n, false)) AS COLUMN_NAME,   CASE am.amcanorder     WHEN true THEN CASE i.indoption[(i.keys).n - 1] & 1       WHEN 1 THEN 'D'       ELSE 'A'     END     ELSE NULL   END AS ASC_OR_DESC,   ci.reltuples AS CARDINALITY,   ci.relpages AS PAGES,   pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(i.indpred, i.indrelid) AS FILTER_CONDITION FROM pg_catalog.pg_class ct   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (ct.relnamespace = n.oid)   JOIN (SELECT i.indexrelid, i.indrelid, i.indoption,           i.indisunique, i.indisclustered, i.indpred,           i.indexprs,           information_schema._pg_expandarray(i.indkey) AS keys         FROM pg_catalog.pg_index i) i     ON (ct.oid = i.indrelid)   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ci ON (ci.oid = i.indexrelid)   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_am am ON (ci.relam = am.oid) WHERE true  AND n.nspname = 'things_db' AND ct.relname = 'thing' ORDER BY NON_UNIQUE, TYPE, INDEX_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2422) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2167) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:224) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgDatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(PgDatabaseMetaData.java:2334) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas on what could cause this problem or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-posting from https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/24010:

You're hitting [#16971](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/16971), which isn't fixed yet in CockroachDB 1.1 or the upcoming 2.0.

The workaround for this issue is to avoid trying to create or modify schemas via JDBC, and instead perform schema management yourself or using an external tool like Flyway.

A motivated Java expert could probably create a dialect that avoids using the _pg_expandarray special record syntax, as well - that's specifically what CockroachDB is tripping up on. That's the part of the query that looks like `(i.keys).n` - what that is doing is asking for the named field 'n' from the record type that lives in `i.keys`. CockroachDB doesn't support record types yet, hence the trouble.